# Kubernetes (GKE) Deployment Update Strategy

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

**Requirement**: I want to use NFS share as persistent volume and update deployment by performing rolling updates (*GKE*).

**Problem**: Persistent disk, volume and NFS share exist and are bound/mounted but when the app code is modified, pushed and built as an image, performing rolling update doesn't update the code.

- Any ideas why?
- Is this recommended update strategy or you'd suggest doing it otherwise?

(*note that using persistent volume is hard requirement.*)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question should include details on exactly how a rolling update is specified

Comment: @JonahBenton either via CLI (kubectl) or GKE web UI (Actions / Rolling Update).